# How do I receive the input to my form in my asp.net action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

this seems super simple, yet I'm having trouble figuring it out.
I have  a asp.net core mvc application, and I need to use a form to send some input to a specific action.

I have this form:

```
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form action="@Url.Action("updateStatus", "Home")">
                            <textarea class="greyback" id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"> Update your status...
                            </textarea>
                            <br><br>
                            <input class="input" type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

The form invokes the action that I want it to, so far so good, but I of course also need the text that is put into the textfield to be sent along, and that I'm having a bit of trouble with.

I have tried looking at the special razor page stuff for making forms that look like so:

```
@using  (Html.BeginForm(“action”,   “controller”))
```

But I don't quite understand how that works, how I can hold onto my css tags, or how I could actually create a textarea tag with this syntax.

What would be the best way to send along this data to the action that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I could actually create a textarea tag with this syntax.

You can use the following code:

```
@Html.TextArea("w3review", "Update your status...", new { @class = "greyback" })
```

result:
[image]

> What would be the best way to send along this data to the action that I want?

There is no difference to use html tags or htmlhelper.Htmlhelper will be rendered to html code which is the same with using html tags directly.